# Is it possible to delay HTTP Response in PHP?

Tags: php, http, request, response

I use JAVA to generate a POST Request to a PHP page( For ex: 192.168.1.2/index.php) I want to get the RESPONSE message after 30s. If it's possible, please give me the solution. 
Much appreciated for any help

Comment: just curious as to why, are you worried about timeout issues?

Comment: Why do this on the PHP side? Leaving aside the implications of running a server side script for 30s, you should contain your business logic to the application not external resources. That is to say, put the delay on the Java side.

Comment: Facebook does this with their client data requests, essentially sending a request and "waiting" for the server to respond. It can be used as a type of push request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the top of your PHP script:

```
<?php

  set_time_limit(0);
  sleep(30);

  // Do stuff here
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sleep(30) //wait 30 seconds
```

Just make sure you have your `max_execution_time` set to a high enough value in your php.ini, otherwise the script will exit before it's complete

Answer (score 0):

You can use sleep() to achieve what you are asking.

Be aware that using hard coded delays like you are suggesting will most likely lead to poor design.

If you are waiting for something to happen on the client side I suggest using ajax to issue a notification.

Answer (score 0):

In your java app

```
  try {
      Thread.sleep(30000L);   // 30s
      // POST REQUEST
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
```